# Rails: make authentication to swagger API via devise or other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, devise, swagger

My goal is log in to Swagger API to get access to endpoints. With auth token in future.

I tryed to put Devise line in ApplicationController:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

But when load http://localhost:3000/api-docs/index.html - system allows to access the API without authentication.

I tryed to uncomment in /config/initializers/rswag-ui.rb:

```
  c.basic_auth_enabled = true
  c.basic_auth_credentials 'username', 'password'
```

but it not this.

Also it did not find the right way to realize Bearer Authentication from official Swagger.io documentation. I do not know is it connected to Devise and do I need to use it.

Which way is good to log in to API via login and password of my Users?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With rswag-ui you should only need to uncomment those lines. No other authentication is needed (like devise).

```
# /config/initializers/rswag-ui.rb

c.basic_auth_enabled = true
c.basic_auth_credentials 'username', 'password'
```

I just did it in my project and it worked straight away, so thought I might as well answer.

Comment: This works, but only for the username/password combination that you specify. Using `devise` would allow you to restrict access to all registered users. (I'm still looking for a way to restrict access to developers only.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using devise, to protect swagger enpoints you can use `authorize` method in `config/routes.rb`

```rb
  authenticate :user do
    mount Rswag::Ui::Engine => '/api-docs'
    mount Rswag::Api::Engine => '/api-docs'
  end
```

[Method doc](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/ActionDispatch%2FRouting%2FMapper:authenticate)

If your API endpoints are protected with devise cookie session, only making requests after a successfully sign in will be enough. But, if your API uses other authentication scheme (Ex. Token) you will need to specify a security scheme in `spec/swagger_helper.rb`.

[Here](https://github.com/rswag/rswag#specifyingtesting-api-security) you can find more details for this configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the answer from @mateusc

If you want to restrict access not only to Devise-registered users, but to a subset (say, only admins) of those users, you can do something like this in `routes.rb`

```
authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.admin? } do
  mount Rswag::Ui::Engine => '/api-docs'
  mount Rswag::Api::Engine => '/api-docs'
end
```

Replace `u.admin?` with a test that's appropriate for your needs.